# Navigation Bar color change

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios6, xcode4.5

I am using Xcode 4.5.2 when setting navigation bar color using tint color property .now navigation bar color has the white shadow above my navigation bar color

Comment: Just a heads up Xcode 4.5 is really old and can't be used with the now mandatory iOS 8 SDK when submitting app. Also include some code to give more of an example what you are doing and what is happening. Which iOS version are you targeting ?

Comment: my app was almost done in xcode 4.5 initially i am targeting ios 6

Comment: i want to submit the app after theme change

Comment: You will need to use Xcode 6 with the iOS 8 SDk if you plan to submit your app. You can set you deployment target to iOS 6 so that your app will be able to be installed on an iOS 6 device.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```